# How to email blocks input field like the one in gmail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email, tags

In gmail when we input an email and press the pace bar, the email form a light blue box, and then I can type in another email so that they are separated. (Similar for tags in Stackoverflow?) How can one actually achieve it? I have looked into [Tagit](https://github.com/hailwood/jQuery-Tagit), but it's no longer under active development. They suggested [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) as the alternative, but I don't see how can I achieve the desired effect with no predetermined list of accepted values (All emails should be accepted!).

Any idea how to make it? It is best not to use jQuery UI for this :).

Answer (score 0):

Check out Auto Tokenization for Select2. It allows users to insert non predefined tags (or email adresses in your case). Make sure you define `tokenSeparators`, for example:

```
$("#input").select2({
    tokenSeparators: [",", " "]}
);
```